# How broadcast and emit internal mechanism work in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, events

I am creating example of broadcast and emit. How it is internally maintain broadcast event lists. Also how angularjs identify which on method it should be executed when broadcast event is called.

Comment: basically broadcast send events to its child scope's and emit send events to its parent scope's

Comment: how angularjs maintain this things internally.

Comment: If you're interested in how things work internally, check out [Build Your Own Angular](http://teropa.info/build-your-own-angular).

Comment: [`$broadcast`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1231) and [`$emit`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1159) are defined in the [rootScope.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js) if you want to study how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us I know If you defined multiple functions on one event,**AngularJs will trigger only one function.The last you defined**.If you call $broadcast('anyEvent'),angularjs will send a signal down to current scope (from where you called).It collects all listeners and event by name and easily calls it.The same thing with $emit,but only to up from scope (not to down)

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave this in the comment section if my reputation allowed it, but I just started becoming an active member on StackOverflow...

Anyway, I myself am not too familiar with implementing Broadcast/Emit functionality within Angular but I did happen to come across, what I thought, was a very well written article on the matter. Hope this helps!

http://www.oakwoodsys.com/angularjs-using-emit-broadcast-open-controller-communication/